# How to replace " switch...case... " with "dictionary" for a better maintainability

Tags: dictionary, case, code-maintainability

In my code, i have switch case such as

```
switch(iSortCol) {
   case1: if(iSortDir="desc"){order1 = order1.OrderByDescending(x=>x.GROUPNAME);
          elseif(iSortDir="asc")order1 = order1.OrderBy (x=>x.GROUPNAME);

   case2: if(iSortDir="desc"){order1 = order1.OrderByDescending(x=>x.GROUPMASTERID);
          elseif(iSortDir="asc")order1 = order1.OrderBy (x=>x.GROUPMASTERID);}
   ....

   case80:

   case81:
}
```

The growing of "switch...case..." leads more maintain work for the code, i am thinking how to covert the code to Dictionary or strategy pattern for a better maintainability.

By the way, the property in order 1 such as `"GROUPNAME"`,`"GROUPMASTERID"` has different type
E.g. the `"GROUPNAME"` in `(x=>x.GROUPNAME)` is string type, but the `"GROUPMASTERID"` in `(x=>x.GROUPMASTERID)` int type.

Could anyone give me some clues, really appreciated

Comment: Something like this? : http://byatool.com/general-coding/orderby-using-a-property-name/    EDIT: Also put the language tag in there. Some people just look at certain languages.

Comment: Cool. joern, it works fine with Dictionary<int,Func<type,Icomparable>>,Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a hardcoded switch statement into a dynamically loaded many-keys-one-value lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921158/converting-a-hardcoded-switch-statement-into-a-dynamically-loaded-many-keys-one)